# how to wrap a promise and keep the return type?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a function that uses an axios instance and has type `async function register(data: RegisterData): Promise<AxiosResponse<UserResponse, any>>`

```
export const register = (data: RegisterData) => api.post<UserResponse>('register', data)
```

Using the vue 3 composition api I am trying to create a wrapper over the form logic. The `request` parameter accepts a `register` function (or other similar functions).

form.ts

```
import {reactive, ref} from 'vue'
import Errors from '../helpers/Errors'
import type {AxiosResponse} from 'axios'

export function useForm<T extends Record<string, any>, R extends (...args: any) => Promise<AxiosResponse>>(init: T, request: R) {
    const form = reactive<T>(init)
    const errors = reactive(new Errors())
    const isLoading = ref(false)

    const makeRequest = () => {
        isLoading.value = true
        errors.clear()
        return request(form)
            .then(response => Promise.resolve(response))
            .catch(e => {
                if (e.response.status === 422) {
                    errors.save(e.response.data.errors)
                }
                return Promise.reject(e)
            })
            .finally(() => isLoading.value = false)
    }


    return {form, errors, isLoading, makeRequest}
}
```

RegisterPage.vue

```
import {useForm} from '../../../composables/form'
import {register} from '../../../api/auth'
// ...
const {form, isLoading, errors, makeRequest} = useForm({
  username: null,
  password: null,
  password_confirmation: null,
  referral_code: null
}, register)
makeRequest() // returns value of Promise<AxiosResponse<any, any>> type
// ...
```

But when I call the wrapper function, it returns the following type `Promise<AxiosResponse<any, any>>`

How can I make the `makeRequest` function return the same type as the `register` function (`Promise<AxiosResponse<UserResponse, any>>`)?

Comment: By specifying the type you want it to be, `const makeRequest: R = ...` ?

Comment: I want the `makeRequest` function to inherit the return type of the `register` function. The answer Tobias S. already solved this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a type assertion for the `makeRequest` function.

```
export function useForm<
  T extends Record<string, any>, 
  R extends (...args: any) => Promise<AxiosResponse>
>(init: T, request: R) {

  /* ... */  

  const makeRequest = (() => {
    /* ... */
  }) as () => ReturnType<R>

  /* ... */
}
```

Now the returned `makeRequest` function will have the correct type.

```
const {form, isLoading, errors, makeRequest} = useForm({
  username: null,
  password: null,
  password_confirmation: null,
  referral_code: null
}, register)

const result = makeRequest()
//     ^? const result: Promise<AxiosResponse<UserResponse, any>>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-ufWJ70X05n9g3EXOAFZPYBDu8T4R-3HXo1i0C1zRABxPRHf19TcYNQ2HWkLStG1AMoB5oLYDAMyzIhwEINAsiWH0XyzUc6TOOgbxQOhYMDdx7SdF0IDddQxByUQ7XYSiQjolBdTgz5BVjOgHWdV1c2AYQmEOCATjOBwxzkrMKBCCBBBwDZzXNGhLjACgUBQGVTi4TTtN0-TDOM0yAH1ilAs5eD2cydL0ywyjWGMLXspAuA0qAtJ07J8XKSokmtO1q204xyHEli2N-RYAHpkt9AA9AB+IA)